# Access ILB ASE (App service environement) API App url from brower

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have created an API App in an ILB ASE, which is not accessible from outside. I know if I create VM under same vnet (where ASE created) then from that VM, I can access this url. Do we have any other way to access this ILB API App ? may be from API App's console or something?

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: If you want to access it from another VNet in azure , you can use Vnet peering and VPN gateway. VPN gateway can also be used from on-premise.

Comment: I also see no other chance then to use another product like Application Gateway or I would even suggest API Management in external mode (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet) - one end public and the other end in the VNET (but a separate network).